# Converting Time Interval to actual time in AM PM in Oracle

Tags: oracle, time, converters

How can i convert the result of select statement of time interval field in respective time in Am/Pm format. 
My Field is:

```
Interval Day(2) To Second(6)
```

I tried this:

```
select To_Char(Att_EntranceTime , 'HH:MI AM') From EMPLOYEEATTENDENCETABLE;
```

however this does not help me, i have also tried to add the basetime from systime to my interval field but that did not help.. can someone suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Intervals can't be directly formatted, as you've discovered. You can add your interval to any date which has its time set to midnight, and then format the resulting date to show the time in your desired format. For example you could add it to today's date using `trunc(sysdate)`:

```
to_char(trunc(sysdate) + my_interval, 'HH:MI AM')
```

You need to truncate it to set the time to midnight; otherwise the result will be your interval plus the current system time.

Or you can use any fixed date; here's an example with some dummy data set-up:

```
create table my_table (my_interval interval day(2) to second(6));
insert into my_table (my_interval) values (interval '0 12:34:56.78' day to second);
insert into my_table (my_interval) values (interval '99 01:02:03.456' day to second);

select my_interval, to_char(date '1970-01-01' + my_interval, 'HH:MI AM') as formatted
from my_table;

MY_INTERVAL          FORMATTED
-------------------- ---------
+00 12:34:56.780000  12:34 PM
+99 01:02:03.456000  01:02 AM
```

The second value shows a potential problem. Your interval is defined to allow a two-digit day number, which means the interval can span anything less than 100 days. If you only extract the time portion you lose that information about the number of days. That may be what you want to happen though. If the interval is supposed to be representing a time of day, which wanting to show AM/PM implies - and it's unusual to store an actual time separate from its date - then having or allowing a number of days seems strange.